# HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize - The following assembly contains no mapped classes

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am using NHibernate in my web application. So far I have created this following hibernate mapping object class:

```
namespace Dao {
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for User
    /// </summary>
    public class User {
        private int _id;

        public int Id {
            get {
                return _id;
            }

            private set {
                _id = value;
            }
        }

        private string _name;

        public string Name {
            get {
                return _name;
            }

            set {
                _name = value;
            }
        }

        public User() {

        }
    }
}
```

The following code:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.Configure();
configuration.SetProperty("connection.connection_string", WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString);            
HbmSerializer.Default.Validate = true;
configuration.AddInputStream(HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));            
configuration.AddDirectory(new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Code/Dao")));
SessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
SchemaExport se = new SchemaExport(configuration);
se.Drop(false, true);
se.Create(false, true);
```

from the constructor of the class `NHibernateModule : IHttpModule`.

This is my hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Dao" assembly="Dao">

<class name="Dao.User" table="User">
  <id name="Id" column="Id">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property name="Name" column="Name" length="50"/>
</class>
```

Now the class `User` is in Dao folder of App_Code, the hbm.xml resides in the same Dao folder and the class `NHibernateModule` is in the HttpModules folder of App_Code:

```
App_Code
|-------Dao
|          |---User.cs
|          |---NHibernateMapping.hbm.xml
|-------HttpModules
           |---NHibernateModule.cs
```

When I am running the application I am getting:

```
[MappingException: The following assembly contains no mapped classes: App_Code.qy81yxpd, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]
NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.HbmSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream, Assembly assembly) +2855
NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.HbmSerializer.Serialize(Assembly assembly) +132
HttpModules.NHibernateModule..cctor() in e:\EMS\App_Code\HttpModules\NHibernateModule.cs:26
```

Any information will be very helpful to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set your hbm.xml file to be embedded resource?

Comment: how can I set the embedded resource?

Comment: Right-click on the XML file and go to Properties, open 'Build Action' drop down list and choose - Embedded Resource.